# Does poi-objectmapper maps the excel sheet to a nested object? If so, what should be done?

Tags: excel, apache-poi

I'm trying to map the excel sheet to pojo using poi-object-mapper. It is working fine if the excel header name matches with the property name. But not working on a nested object.

I have a Employee Object that has a address object. How to map the street name in excel sheet to address.streetname?

```
public class Employee {
//@SheetColumn("Name")
private String name;

//@SheetColumn("Age")
private Integer age;


private Address address;
}
```

Comment: Can you show us your code to help you ?

Comment: @Fizik26  I have edited my question with the code.